# C code to find number of digits in integer is not working as per.suggest modifications

Tags: c

here is the link to the file(google docs link) containing my code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int len(int);
void main()
{
    int n,p;
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=len(n);
    printf("length of entered number is %d",p);
}
int len(int num)
{
    int i,c,b;
    for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
        b=10*i;
        if(num<b) {
            return(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also suggest you listen to your compiler and the warnings it gives you. And if it doesn't give you warnings then you need to enable more warnings. There are a few problems with the code you show, all detecable by the compiler.

Comment: May be you are trying to do `b=pow(10, i)`. But this is not a good idea. See the answers for better implementation

Comment: Notice that "number of digits in integer" and "length of entered number is" is potentially different when considering zero and negative numbers.

Comment: That's some food for thought.I will keep that  in mind. @chux

Answer (score 3):

Computing `b=10*i;` makes no logical sense. Did you want to raise 10 to a given *power*?

The normal way of solving this problem is to repeatedly divide by 10 until 0 is reached (using integer arithmetic), and count the number of divisions made. That is the number of digits in the original number. This method is also not vulnerable to integer overflow:

```
unsigned digits = 0;
for (; num /= 10; ++digits);
return digits;
```

Comment: actualy correct method was to calculate pow(10,i) instead of 10*i. now the code is working fine.

Comment: Don't use pow for this: i) it's expensive, ii) you risk overflowing an `int`, iii) can go off due to floating point. `pow(x, y)` is typically implemented as `exp (y log x)` in C. Repeated division by 10 is better in every respect.

Comment: `for (; num /= 10; ++digits);` fails for `num==0` as zero is usually considered a one digit number..  Consider `do { ++digits; } while (num /= 10);`

Comment: @chux: I probably should have mentioned zero as a special case. To me, defining the number of digits necessary to hold 0 is down to personal choice (I like to think of 0 as requiring 0 digits to store, but then I guess mathematicians are strange folk!)

Answer (score 1):

```
int len(int num){
    int i = 0;

    if(num == 0)
        return 1;

    while(num!=0){
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

here we divide num by 10 until it reaches 0, and each time loop executes we increment the count `i++`

Comment: thanks for the help.but my code is now working when i replaced 10*i with pow(10,i).

Comment: @frontMatter Ok its working, but consider changing it. Your for loop only goes 50 times, it works but its not right. You should set something else as end condition. Also, int c...i didn't see where you used it

Comment: i used 50 since it was a constraint for the problem i was working on. and int c, thanks for ponting out.

Comment: Note that `len(-123)` returns 1. I'd expect 3.

Comment: my bad..changed it

Answer (score -1):

frontmatter i am not able to recognize your answer but i think this following code is helpful as per your title.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char a[50000];
    int i,c=0;
    printf("enter number:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(a);
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>=0 || a[i]<=9)
        {
            c++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n %d digit number",c);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` = one cat potentially eaten due to undefined behaviour. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: thanks for the help.but my code is now working when i replaced 10*i with pow(10,i)